# Replacing single quotes with double quotes in JS

Tags: javascript, vb.net, quotes

We are currently in the process of translating our VBScript to javascript and one of the steps is to remove single quotes `'` and use double quotes instead `"`.

I have the following line of code in the HTML header:

```
document.write("<div style='position:absolute;padding-left:10px;padding-top:50px;color:red;font-size:13pt' id='divtest'><%=resxPleaseWait%><marquee style='border-top:solid 1px black' DIRECTION=RIGHT BEHAVIOR=SCROLL SCROLLAMOUNT=10 SCROLLDELAY=200>.</marquee>  </div>")
```

This used to be VB script but is now being written as JS.

Further down the page the ID `divtest` is called. In replacing the single quotes this functionality breaks and I cannot think of an alternative. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an alternative: don't replace the quotes. JavaScript understands both quotes without any problems. If you really want to, though, then you can switch them around, since HTML is also completely indifferent to which quotes you are using. And if that's not good either, then you can backslash-escape any inner quotes. Also, be sure the "functionality breaks" is not due to `<%=resxPleaseWait%>`, which has no meaning to JavaScript. What does "`divtest` is called" even mean? And using `<marquee>`... [Ugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element).

Comment: Amadan, I have to replace all single quotes because its what was asked of me by my project manager, and as far as "divtest is called" I mean it is referenced later in the code. Either way I used backslash-escape. I didn't realise I could do that. Rookie error I guess. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DoubleQuotes " in your javascript by escaping them like this \".

```
document.write("<div style=\"position:absolute;padding-left:10px;padding-top:50px;color:red;font-size:13pt\" id=\"divtest\"><%=resxPleaseWait%>  <marquee style=\"border-top:solid 1px black\" DIRECTION=\"RIGHT\" BEHAVIOR=\"SCROLL\" SCROLLAMOUNT=\"10\" SCROLLDELAY=\"200\">.</marquee>  </div>")
```

The errors you are experiencing may have been caused by not placing quotes around the
marquee properties.
I corrected this too in the above code.

Comment: There are equal signs bot no quotes. I agree this shouldn't pose a problem. But I always quote properties in HTML

Comment: This worked great! Thanks a lot. I didn't realise I could escape like that. Thanks again.